# Разделитель для элементов ListvIew

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли и если да то как сделать так, чтобы разделитель (divider) отображался только у некоторых элементов ListView согласно некоторому условию? Скажем, в ListView есть 20 элементов и тоьлко у трех из них нужно отображать этот самый divider а у остальных скрывать. Как сделать такое? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Имеет смысл добавить в вопрос код, имеющий к вопросу непосредственное отношение.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте ваш "разделитель" в разметку элемента списка, и определяйте, нужно ли его показывать в методе getView адаптера

Comment: я так и сделал но это не сработало

Comment: @JuniorThree значит не так сделали.

Answer (score 0):

Дополню ответ metalurgu'a. Следует понимать, что в методе getView надо в полном объеме описывать все поведения вьюшек, т.е. если есть какие-то условия, то обязательно описывать все состояния, например

```
if (object.isVisible()) {
   divider.setVisibility(View.Visible);
} else {
   divider.setVisibility(View.Gone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Специально для того, чтобы можно было в одном списке отображать айтемы разного вида, в адаптере существуют методы `getItemViewType()` и  `getViewTypeCount()` - первый определяет условие, при котором должен отображаться тот или иной айтем, второй количество айтемов разного вида.

Делаете две разметки(в вашем случае будет уместно использовать `include` поскольку отличия только в дивидере): один айтем без дивидера, второй с дивидером. Для списка дивидеры отключаете вовсе. В `getItemViewType` задаете условия, когда какой отображать и готово.

[Подробнее](http://learnncode.co/2014/01/21/listview-getviewtype-and-getviewtypecount-in-action/)